# Grid View Extends too far in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

My Grid view in C# asp.net extends too far when editing and its causing a scroll bar at the bottom I've searched for several solutions but unable to find anything that works any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: That's lovely. May we see some code?

Comment: It can be easy to find out the problem if you post the markup code.

Answer (score 0):

Change the AutoSize property of the GridView's Column to False.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that you are not AutoGenerating the Columns / Fields as well. set that property to False as well